# What is the syntax for invoking GnuWin32's find exec on windows cmd shell?

Tags: windows, cmd, gnuwin32

Invoking GnuWin32's `find.exe . -name "foo" -exec backup.bat {} \;` produces the following error:

```
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

What is the proper syntax?

Answer (score 1):

Call GnuWin32 find.exe this way:

```
find.exe . -name "foo" -exec backup.bat {} ;
```

Escaping the semicolon is unnecessary in the Windows Command Prompt.